# How to get one-bit changed permutations?

Tags: list-manipulation

The following

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, 2] // Permutations
```

produces a list of permutations of `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}`.

If I want to pick ones with two adjacent elements have exactly one bit changes, how to do so?

Example:

- `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}` **Rejected** because these two adjacent elements `{0, 1}` and `{1, 0}` have two bits change.
- `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}` **OK**

**Note**: the first and the last elements are also considered as adjacent elements.

Comment: For searching purposes: this is asking for permutations ordered by a Gray code.

Comment: For an interesting cross-reference from the world of genetics, see [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/108617/1136) at biology.stackexchange by Rosemarie Swanson, who represented the genetic code as a 'codon wheel' using Gray coding.   The original article is [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02460068)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1:** Write a function that checks whether two lists of `0` and `1` differ only in one bit:

```
oneBitChangeQ[a_,b_]:=HammingDistance[a,b]<=1;
```

For example

```
oneBitChangeQ[{0,0,1},{1,1,1}]
(* False *)

oneBitChangeQ[{0,0,1},{0,1,1}]
(* True *)
```

**Step 2.** Write a function that checks whether in a give list of lists of `0` and `1`, all adjacent elements (including last and first) differ only in one bit:

```
admissibleQ[m_]:=And@@MapThread[oneBitChangeQ,{m,RotateRight[m]}];
```

For example

```
admissibleQ[{{0,0},{0,1},{1,1}}]
(* False *)

admissibleQ[{{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{1,0}}]
(* True *)
```

**Step 3.** Apply to your problem:

```
Tuples[{0,1},2]//Permutations//Select[admissibleQ]
```

This gives

```
{{{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{1,0}},
 {{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},
 {{0,1},{0,0},{1,0},{1,1}},
 {{0,1},{1,1},{1,0},{0,0}},
 {{1,0},{0,0},{0,1},{1,1}},
 {{1,0},{1,1},{0,1},{0,0}},
 {{1,1},{0,1},{0,0},{1,0}},
 {{1,1},{1,0},{0,0},{0,1}}}
```

**Note.** There will be lots of approaches. You may also want to think of this in terms of graphs, Eulerian cycles on the binary cube.

Answer (score 3):

Loosely following @user293787's suggestion: we can calculate the [Hamiltonian cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) on the [$n$-cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube),

```
n = 3;
c = FindHamiltonianCycle[HypercubeGraph[n], All][[All, All, 1]]
(*    {{1, 3, 7, 8, 4, 2, 6, 5},
       {1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 5},
       {1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 3, 7, 5},
       {1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5},
       {1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 3},
       {1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3}}    *)
```

Expressed in terms of the vertex coordinates, as requested by the OP:

```
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
t[[#]] & /@ c
(*    {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}    *)
```

But careful: the number of such Hamiltonian cycles grows very rapidly with $n$, as described by [OEIS-A066037](http://oeis.org/A066037):

| $n$ | number of cycles |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1344 |
| 5 | 906545760 |
| 6 | 35838213722570883870720 |

For this reason it may be more sensible to calculate only a small number of such Hamiltonian cycles by specifying something other than `All` as the second argument to [`FindHamiltonianCycle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianCycle.html). For example, get a single cycle for $n=12$:

```
n = 12;
c = FindHamiltonianCycle[HypercubeGraph[n]][[All, All, 1]];
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
t[[#]] & /@ c
(*    {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        ...
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}    *)
```